# Explode array from mysql and assign to variables PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables

OK so in the database I have a column that contains data like this
:Novice:Intermediate:Advanced
( some columns have more than the 3 listed above )

What I'm trying to do is explode at the : and then assign the exploded values to variables

At most there are 4 bits of data separated by : so a max of 4 variables

Here is the code I have so far

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venues",$dbc);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

do{
$eventtype = explode(':',$result['def_sessions']);  
list($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4) = $eventtype;
//print_r(explode(":",$result['def_sessions']));
echo $var1.'<br>'.$var2.'<br>'.$var3.'<br>'.$var4;
}while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
```

It works ( to an extent )
For example record ID 13 has this in the column
:Novice:Novice/Intermediate:Intermediate/Advanced:Advanced:

The output however does NOT display the final 
Advanced

it only displays 
Novice
Novice/Intermediate
Intermediate/Advanced

Anyone help me please I am pulling hair out badly here .

I have also tried adding another $var5 but that doesnt help

Comment: because there is : at starting which creates first element as "" and when its printed  you don't see anything

Comment: you should normalize your db

Comment: use `list($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4) = array_filter($eventtype);`

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add $var5 to the list()

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venues WHERE id ='30'",$dbc);
 $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

 do{
$eventtype = explode(':',$result['def_sessions']);  
list($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4,$var5) = $eventtype;
 //print_r(explode(":",$result['def_sessions']));
echo $var1.'<br>'.$var2.'<br>'.$var3.'<br>'.$var4.'<br>'.$var5;
 }while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
```

Working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venues",$dbc);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$i=0;
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $var1[$i]=$row['Novice'];
    $var2[$i]=$row['Intermediate'];
    $var3[$i]=$row['Advanced '];
    echo $var1[$i].'<br>'.$var2[$i].'<br>'.$var3[$i].'<br>';
    $i++;
    }
```

Comment: The values arent always the same and neither is the amount of values stored in the column seperated by :

Answer (score 0):

Your problem it´s how you are trying to get the values from the table and explode.

I use something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venues",$dbc);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$def_sessions = row(number of yor row);
$eventtype = explode(":", def_sessions);
$val0 = $eventtype[0];
$val1 = $eventtype[1];
...
}
```